# ng-repeat based on key in JSON - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

Im working on a project where i populate some `JSON` from *Google Tag Manager API* and send this data to the frontend written in AngularJS.

Now, im using `ng-repeat` on a card from *AngularJS Material* and cannot think of a way to actually populate the ng-repeat just like *Google Tag Manager*, the way that i populate is like this:

```
<div class='md-padding' layout="row" layout-wrap>
    <md-card flex="45" flex-sm="100" flex-md="100" flex-xs="100"
             ng-repeat="container in containers | toArray:false |  filter:container">

        <md-toolbar>
            <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
                <h1 class="md-display-3">{{container.account_name}}</h1>
            </div>
        </md-toolbar>
  <md-card-title>

(...) here comes some table code...
```

The main thing is `ng-repeat"container in containers"`

This gives me this result:
[image]

As you can see the ng-repeat creates a card for each accounts, what i would want is that if the `"container.accountId"` is same then populate inside same `<md-card>`.

What i would want is to look like this: (Ignore that this is not the same structure on card, this is taken for googletagmanager.com)

[image]

As you can see `"Account2"` has both `"containers"` inside the same `md-card`

Hope someone can help me, thanks!

Comment: What you do is restructure the data in your controller, then use two nested `ng-repeat`s.

Comment: Would this work with groupBy?

Answer (score 0):

In component.ts file construct a map like [string, array["string"]].

here

key = container account name
value = list of container objects with same container account name

use that map in view file like

```
<md-card ng-repeat="mapobject of map" ..
// heading(mapobject.key)
// repeat using mapobject.value
</md-card>
```

This would solve your problem

Comment: im not using Typescript

Comment: you will using JavaScript for interacting with ui components right?

Comment: Yes if i could reconstruct the JSON inside controller or on the view it would be best, cannot do this in backend

Comment: yes @asim I'm asking you to construct inside controller

Comment: @asim instead of sending container list JSON that you will receive from backend to the view, just construct an object and send to view

Comment: Could you provide an example? @Vijay

Comment: you will receive the container object from backend in controller and you will pass directly to view right?? instead construct an object as i mentioned in answer and send that object to view. In view change the code accordingly to access that object. I hope this explanation helps you

Answer (score 0):

So ive solved it with groupBy filter provided by https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby

So ive used it like this:

```
<div class='md-padding' layout="row" layout-wrap>
    <md-card flex="45" flex-sm="100" flex-md="100" flex-xs="100"
             ng-repeat="(key, value) in containers | groupBy: 'account_name'">
```

By using `(key,value)` and then `groupBy` based on `key(account_name)`

Thanks :)